# ESP8266 - is .Net possible?

Tags: .net, arduino, iot, esp8266

Looking to know if it is at all possible to develop for the ESP8266 (I have the WeMos D1 Mini) using C# or if I'm stuck with Arduino Sketch?

I've looked around on the net, but not finding any guides or examples, so it does feel like my answer will be "No" but posting anyway in case someone knows of anything to the contrary :)

Comment: Well, you can write a C# marschaller, that uses the Arduino-Library for the ESP8266.

Comment: Oh if I had that knowledge, I would :) Was hoping that there already existed something, for example something for the .net micro-framework

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can't. But maybe comfortable for you to write codes in C++ using Visual Studio's plugin [Visual Micro](http://www.visualmicro.com/) instead of programming in native Arduino IDE.

Comment: Ok, I guess I just have to accept that :) Already using Visual Micro. Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason you couldn't write bindings for C# to use the native SDK but I don't think such a thing exists at present.

That said you don't have to use Arduino, you can use the [NodeMCU firmware](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware) and write in Lua using any IDE, or you could use Eclipse and write in c, there are lots of possibilities...

Comment: I'm working with C :) NodeMCU ate up all the resources :)